# How could I pack all js files, CSS , embedded scripts into a js plugin

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I wrote a JS plugin to client's website can load comments from our database via CORS method.

My goal is to wrapper my whole code into an easily embeddable plugin.

Just like the facebook js plugin, Google Analytics plugin. They are easy to install on a website.

My plugin depends on other libraries, such as jquery, underscore, backbone, handlebars, and also my scripts and CSS.
I studied `Require.js` it seems suitable to do this job for me.

I need to generate an all-in-one javascript plugin, e.g.,. "awesome-comments.min.js".

Some articles suggest me to put all the dependent js files with `require.config`.

But I'm having no idea how could I do other stuff such as my  js scripts with require.js.

Is there any similar application or tutorial has the same function. Thanks.

## sample_with_requireJS.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/require.js" data-main="js/main"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="load_awesome_comments"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## js/main.js

```
　　require.config({
　　　　baseUrl: "http://mywebsite/assets/",
　　　　paths: {
　　　　　　"jquery": "jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1",
　　　　　　"underscor": "~~~",
  ...
　　　　}
　　});
```

## sample-without-requireJS.html (This is my current workable html sample, mixed with js, css and html DOM)

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js"/>
        <script src="http://localhost:3001/assets/jquery-9e7b5a8e0157d7776b987d8963c9c786.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

    <style>
    body {
        /*background-color: linen;*/
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click','.show-more',function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            ....
        });
    });


      window.onload = function(){
        .....
      }

      Handlebars.registerHelper('if_even', function(conditional, options) {
        ....
      });



    </script>

    <!-- Setup our templates -->

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="load_awesome_comments"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function hideFurtherComments(){
                .....
            }

            var Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
                ....

            });

            var Comments = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Comment,
                url: fetch_comments_url,
                initialize: function() {
                    ....
                },
                deferred: Function.constructor.prototype,
                fetchSuccess: function(collection, response) {
                    collection.deferred.resolve();
                },

            });

            var comments = new Comments();
            var CommentView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $("#comments_section"),
                render: function() {
                  ....
                },
            });

            var EmptyCommentView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $("#empty_comments_list"),
                render: function() {
                  ....
                },
            });

            var commentView = new CommentView({
                collection: comments
            });
            var emptyCommentView = new EmptyCommentView({
                collection: comments
            });

            comments.deferred.done(function() {
                ....
            });

        });
        var og_url = $("meta[property='og:url']").attr("content");
        $("#original_news_article_link").attr("href", og_url)

    </script>
    <script src="js/require.js" defer async="true" ></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a look at https://webpack.github.io and http://browserify.org/. Their purpose is to do exactly what you need. You pack all of your Javascript code, Javascript dependencies and CSS in one sole JavaScript file.

The *advantage* of this method is that users can make use of your module just by including a *single JavaScript file*; no need to worry about dependencies.

The drawback is that, given that the dependencies are all included in the single file, if in a page you have three modules packed this way that use jQuery, for example, *the jQuery code will be downloaded three times*.